# How do I install Scala's Breeze library using Gradle?

Tags: scala, gradle

I know on [its website](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Installation), Breeze recommends to install using SBT.
But the project I'm working on is using gradle, so I'm trying to figure out how do to specify the breeze info in build.gradle.

Here is the simplified structure of the project:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
            └── MainFile.scala
```

My build.gradle file looks like the following

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4'
    compile group: 'org.scalanlp', name: 'breeze_2.10', version: '0.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'MainFile'
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

And the MainFile.scala looks like the following:

```
import breeze.linalg._

object MainFile {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("In Main")

    val x = DenseVector.zeros[Double](5)
  }
}
```

To build the project, I run the following command from the command line in the source directory of the project:

```
> ./gradlew clean build
```

which built successfully.

But when I tried to run the jar file, I got the following error:

```
> scala build/libs/Numerical.jar 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: breeze.storage.Zero
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

Is anything missing in the gradle.build or the build process?

Please pardon me for the dump question as I'm pretty new to the Java/Scala ecosystem.

Comment: You need to include the classpath to the `breeze` jar with `scala -cp <path>`.

Comment: hi @erip, could you be more specific? What's the <path> variable and where should I run that command? Thank you!

Comment: Wherever your breeze jar is.